# Is *ip and ip the same thing?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int  var = 20;   /* actual variable declaration */
   int  *ip;        /* pointer variable declaration */

   ip = &var;  /* store address of var in pointer variable*/

   printf("Address of var variable: %x\n", &var  );

   /* address stored in pointer variable */
   printf("Address stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip );

   /* access the value using the pointer */
   printf("Value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip );

   return 0;
}
```

In this example, there is *ip and there is ip. I know that *ip is used to declare the pointer, but is *ip the same thing as ip? Why didn't `ip = &var` use the *?

Comment: The declaration could also be `int*  ip`

Comment: The `*`, `[]`, and `()` operators all have different meanings in a *declaration* vs. an *expression*.  In a declaration, `*` indicates that the thing being declared has pointer type.  The *variable* `ip` is a stores a pointer value (an address); in this case, the result of  `&var`.  The *expression* `*ip` in the last `printf` statement *dereferences* the variable `ip` and evaluates to the value of whatever `ip` is pointing to.